# exit status for Linux find command always shows success

Tags: bash, shell, find, exitstatus

I intend to use the Linux "find" command from inside a script. I am just bothered if the "find" command finds the executable in any of the paths mentioned, and not about the exact path. I'm testing the below:

```
find /usr/bin /usr/sbin /bin /sbin -name ntpd > /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?
0

find /usr/bin /usr/sbin /bin /sbin -name ntp > /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?
0

find /usr/bin /usr/sbin /bin /sbin -name ntpd
/usr/sbin/ntpd

# find /usr/bin /usr/sbin /bin /sbin -name ntp
#
```

Why is `find` giving an exit status of `0`, in both cases, whether it finds or doesn't find the executable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`find` doesn't change the exit status when the specified file can't be found. You can pipe its output to `grep` to check it outputs anything:

```
if find /usr/bin /usr/sbin /bin /sbin -name ntpd | grep -q ^ ; then
    echo Found
else
    echo Not found
fi
```

Comment: @choroba That's a pretty cool one. Very smart. Thanks a ton. This saves me atleast 3-4 code lines :)